# Add vsto runtime in installer .msi package

Tags: vb.net, installation, windows-installer

I have a Outlook add-in installer  made using visual studio installer. I wish to add vsto runtime into my installer package so that user is not required  to install it manually. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this runtime is installed as part of the main Office installation? It looks like the runtime is just needed for server installations: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx** (have a good read of this link and its linked sub-pages).

Apart from that, if you require more advanced installer features you should seriously consider switching to using the [**WiX toolkit**](http://wixtoolset.org/) (free and open source, here are some [**quick start suggestions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)) or something easier  and faster to learn such as the free version of [**Advanced Installer**](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). There is a "**Prerequisites**" view in Advanced Installer with several versions of the runtime that can be added. There is a free version of the tool, but I am not sure what features are available for use without a license.